# (VHDL) How to assign a summation result partially in one clock

Tags: concatenation, vhdl, partial

I am trying to implement this on VHDL:

```
a<=(b+c)/16;
```

I have tried this, but synthesis did not accept it.

```
signal b,c   : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal a     : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal dummy : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

(a & dummy) <= ("00000" & b) + ("00000" & 'c');
```

then I was to use a but it failed. (Operation & cannot be associated with a formal of mode OUT.)

Any suggestions?
Thanks,
Cem

Comment: Following Martin and Brian's answers the purpose of strong typing - distinguishing between std_logic_vector, unsigned and signed is to prevent accidental mixing of signed and unsigned numbers in math when evaluating less than zero. When dealing with unsigned numbers (leading zeros) you can type convert with impunity - `(a & dummy) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned ("00000" & b) + unsigned ("00000" & c));`. Your code is incompatible with some revisions of IEEE Std 1076 (< -2008) where elements must be the same size in an aggregate target (use `sum` as the target, add `a <= sum(12 downto 4);`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ieee.numeric_std` and declare a,b,c,dummy as `unsigned` rather than `std_logic_vector`. Or `signed` if that's what your application calls for.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your first attempt and make that `a`, `b` and `c` are numerical types.  `std_logic_vector` has no numerical meaning, so you can't do arithmetic on them.

Either make them all `integer`s, or do as Brian suggests, and use `ieee.numeric_std` and the `signed` or `unsigned` vector types.